# VS2017: Unsupported shader model specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I'm just trying to build this already completed open source file (a CRT filter) in VS2017, but it refuses to build and every time I get the same error: Unsupported shader model specified "fx_4_0_level_9_3"

Anyone have any idea for a fix or work around, I've very new to VS and am just trying to change something very simple and this error is all that's standing in my way. When I change the shader model it causes the code to throw errors, and I really can't understand why this old shader model isn't supported, is it something I need to download?

I'm trying to change the CRTSimSource file located here: https://piratehearts.itch.io/supercrt

Comment: Yeah, I got that link from searching my problem which is the first thing I did, it doesn't explain in any way what is going wrong or why the shader is unsupported.

Comment: I suppose them being deprecated didn't click. So basically if I want to work with this file I'm either going to need to refactor it or use an older version of D3D?

Comment: I love how I come here asking for help and I don't get any actual answers to my questions just someone smugly talking down to me. Great site. Thanks Retired Ninja, you're a real hero of the community. Good to see you guys are so accepting of new people with honest questions.